# How to disable a button on p:fileUpload component by default?

Tags: jsf, events, file-upload, primefaces

I want the upload button to be disabled when user sees the upload file component the first time. Because if he hasn't chosen type for the file it shouldn't be possible to upload a file.

I can make it so, that the component gets disabled when choosing the empty (null) selection in the fileUpload-component. So it works on ajax `change` event, but how to disable it on creation of the component?

Here's how it works. When a type is selected the button gets enabled and when a type is not selected it gets disabled. However, when the client enters the view, a type is NOT selected but still the upload button is enabled. How to disable it in that situation? Is there a way to make it disabled until an event enables it?

```
        <p:fileUpload id="fileUploadComponent" 
            fileUploadListener="#{fileAttachmentController.handleFileUpload}"
            ...other attributes..
            disabled="#{!fileAttachmentController.typeIsSelected}"
            ...other attributes..
        </p:fileUpload>
```

Comment: Did you check the value of the isTypeSelected? Does it work if you (for trying) use a commandButton?

Comment: You can add the "Did you check the value of the isTypeSelected? It should work if it's set to false in the @ViewScope backing bean on declaration." And I will check it as the correct answer :) I had forgotten that particular value as "true" since it was originally typeNotYetSelected... I guess I was too tired yesterday.